# How to calculate change in percentage in a select query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select  current_revenue ,  initial_revenue from T_revenue;
```

[image: you can fine sample data here]

How to calculate the change in percentage?

Like :- Change in rev % = ((current_revenue - initial_revenue) / initial_revenue ) *100

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  You may need to handle the case where `initial_revenue` is 0 though.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT current_revenue, initial_revenue, 
       ((current_revenue - initial_revenue) / initial_revenue * 100.0) AS Percent
FROM T_revenue
```

If you are interested in rounding the percentages, I can explain on how to do that too.